# Dynamics ax 2012 Cannot sort data of reference group type field on grid

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

1. I create a temporary table TmpTable(TradeAgreement)
2. In Relations, I refer TradeAgreement field of TmpTable with RecId field of table TradeAgreementTable.
3. I create a form TmpForm with datasource is TmpTable

   ```
    public class FormRun extends ObjectRun
    {
        TmpTable tmpTable;
    }

    public void init()
    {
        TradeAgreementTable tradeAgreement;
        super();
        while select tradeAgreement
        {
            tmpTable.clear();
            tmpTable.TradeAgreement = tradeAgreement.RecId;
            tmpTable.write();
        }

        TmpTable.setTmpData(tmpTable);
        TmpTable_ds.executeQuery();
    }
   ```
4. I open TmpForm to see result and try to sort but nothing happens

[image: Sort Ascending]

[image: Sort Descending]

Comment: An easy way out is to copy and show the trade agreement key field instead.

Comment: I found the root cause : my TmpTable table has Table Type is "In Memory", when change Table Type from "In Memory" to "Regular", everything is OK. But i don't know exactly why. Can you help me?

Comment: Well, in-memory temp tables are different, specifically they do not join well with regular tables which is needed here. You can make your table Temp-DB instead.

Comment: Many thanks, i will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Set you table type to `TempDB` and then your data can be filtered and sorted like regular tables.